# Should I just accept that data is strongly not normal when changing families for a Generalised Linear Model has not worked?

Tags: r, model

I initially tested my data with ANOVA, but upon finding it to be not normally distributed I tried a Kruskal test. This did not make any difference either, so I tried a GLM, taking into account the discrete variables and trying different families. This seemed to be the best:

```
model1<-glm(HSP~Site,family = poisson (link = sqrt), data=dframe1)
```

but I looked at the residuals and found that the data is still not normal despite the transformation.

I then read something about GLS when this does not work:

```
    ###Generalised Least Squares
    library(nlme)
    model1<-gls(HSP~Site, data=dframe1)
    variance.Site<-varIdent(~Site)
    model2<-gls(HSP~Site,weights=variance.Site,data=dframe1)
    anova(model1,model2);AIC(model1,model2)
    AIC(model1,model2)
```

This is as far as I have got...And how do I get a p-value out of this?

`dput()` for my data:

```
    structure(list(Site = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L
    ), HSP = c(4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
    2L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
    4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L)), .Names = c("Site", 
    "HSP"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -90L))
```

Should I accept that the data is naturally not of a normal distribution and therefore accept that HSP does not vary due to different sites, or is there another model that I can use which would be better for my data?

Comment: Normality of "data" whatever that actually means to you is not an assumption of general linear models. In fact normality of _errors_ (not the outcome variable) is the assumption of linear models, and I doubt you examined residuals from the haphazard manner in which you described your coding.

Comment: Here are the functions I used to inspect residuals: `sresid<-(model1$residuals-mean(model1$residuals))/sd(model1$residuals)
shapiro.test(sresid)`.

Comment: You didn't describe examining the residuals initially . It's not particularly important to have normality anyway. It's much more important to have homoschedasticity. There's also no point in going to mixed models since you are only using the simplest of models.

Comment: On CV, how to do things in R is off-topic, but how to analyse the data is on. Specifying Poisson seems to make more sense given that the data are clearly discrete; but if these are counts then the upper limit of 5 seems hard; is that a theoretical maximum? Indeed, are these counts at all, or some kind of grade or score? If the later, I'd prescribe an ordinal logit model. The larger point is that there is not enough detail here about your problem and your data to comment well on what you are doing. (My Googling yielded Henoch–Schönlein purpura, which may be a lucky hit, or complete nonsense.)

Comment: (It remains true, as pointed out by @jlhoward in an excellent answer, that there is does not seem to be much structure here. Also, you won't get normal residuals out of data like this, but that is largely immaterial.)

Comment: These are scores for the presence of a particular protein in epithelia of various worms at different sites, 1 is low, and 5 is the highest.

Comment: From what you say, Poisson and indeed GLMs are misapplied here. Ordinal logit sounds more appropriate.

Comment: @Nick Cox. How would  I do an ordinal logic model? (I have not come across those before)

Comment: That's an ordinal logi**t** model, as previously. If you want to know how to do it in R, that's off-topic here, as previously, and I wouldn't be the person to ask any way, but I am sure that there are dedicated functions and/or packages. Ordinal logit models are just perhaps the most commonly used for ordinal responses; there are many others and indeed entire monographs on this, such as http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470082895.html

Comment: The larger point remains that there is not much structure evident here, so quite how you model that lack of structure is secondary, just that some kinds of models are statistically much more appropriate than others. You did seem concerned about coming up with inferential results, but tell us: what structure can you identify in the graph of scientific or practical interest or importance?

Comment: What do you mean by 'lack of structure?'These are the scores that have been assigned by teams of students (including replicates within the teams) to the amount of staining of a heat shock protein present in the epithelia of an earthworm. The actual species is unknown so far, but Eisenia fetida is a likely candidate. I would expect that the heat shock protein expression would be higher in the contaminated sites (metal pollution for instance) and less in the control group- which is group 6. Obviously there is arbitrary error as the different teams have to judge how much staining there is.

Comment: Lack of structure means that you can't see a pattern that you want to think about on the graph, or more generally in the data. There isn't a formal definition; that's the whole point. It's whatever excites or interests the scientist. For example, you might have a reason for expecting Site 4 to show lower numbers, and so forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice would be to examine the data before jumping into modeling.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=Site,y=HSP)) +
  geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(width=.1)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data="mean_cl_boot",color="red")
```

[image]

I don't see much evidence that `Site` influences `HSP` in a systematic way. There is, however, some evidence that the distribution of `HSP` is different at different sites.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(HSP))) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(fill=factor(Site)))+
  facet_wrap(~Site,nc=5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help. However, when I put in the code that you have suggested R gives this output: Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class function                   I apologise if it is something ignorant I am doing? I have got ggplot2 installed.

Comment: Read the documentation on `ggplot`. The first argument is a data frame containing your data. I called this `df`.

Comment: That would make sense, sorry. It works now. :-)

Comment: By the way, does the red line indicate the confidence intervals?

Comment: Yes, 95% CL. You can change that using `conf.int=...` in the call to `stat_summary(...)`. The documentation isn't great on this. `"mean_cl_boot"` is a ggplot wrapper for the function `smean.cl.boot(...)` in the `Hmisc` package. Read the documentation on that to see what the extra arguments are. You can also use other functions, as in `fun.data="maen_sdl"`, etc. The documentation on `stat_summary(...)` does identify these in the examples.